# How to Display images in a simpleAdapter form URLs (XML feed)?

Tags: xml, image, url, imageview, simpleadapter

Can anyone please help me to Display images in a simpleAdapter form URLs. I have these URLs in my XML file. in my simpleAdapter I have "R.drawable.imageView1"

I can display text but can't get the image. I have a method to get the URL from the XML called-

.getImage();

this method will retrieve an URL.

how can I give the URL in to the "R.drawable.imageView1"  ?

Thanks a Lot!

Answer (score 0):

I found that the Android Image Manager (http://code.google.com/p/android-image-manager/) (BSD license) made it a lot easier.  It allows you to do what you want to do without a bunch of extra code to download the image asynchronously, etc.